# Получить поля из массива объектов, сгруппированные по объектам

Tags: массивы, vue.js, объекты

У меня есть массив Proxy-объектов artists[]. Сами по себе Proxy также являются массивами объектов (насколько я понял). У каждого из внутренних объектов есть поле "artistName" (скриншот). Причём у третьего Proxy два таких объекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить примерно следующее:

```
[
  ["Queen"],
  ["Pink Floyd"],
  ["Elvis Presley", "Pink Floyd"],
]
```

То есть на выходе получается группировка artistName по каждому Proxy-объекту.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено. Так как в данном случае два уровня массивов, то следует сделать два цикла `map()`:

```
const groupedArtists = artists.map(el => el.map(elem => elem.artistName))
~~
```